# Watir-Webdriver - Putting a list into an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, list, automation, watir

I am trying to compare 2 dropdown lists for automation but I keep getting an error.

The HTML code:

```
<div class="ngCellText col1 colt1" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">Our Equipment</span></div>
```

My Watir code:

```
@activityList = Array.new
@activityList = @browser.select_list(:xpath,'//*[@id="aBreakDown"]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/span').option
puts @activityList
```

Comment: HTML:<div class="ngCellText col1 colt1" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">Our Equipment</span></div>

Comment: add error message please

Comment: Hi Alex,  I just figured it out, now i got to put a for loop and hopefully walla!

but just incase you want to know the message was:     #<Watir::Option:0x00000002fdefd8>
   Then job should be no longer editable # features/step_definitions/LockedJobs
rb:130

the code i used to fix it is:
 activityList = Array.new
 browser.span(:xpath,'//*[@id="npTime"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/span').when_present.click
 activityList = @browser.select_list(:index,0).select_value("0")
    puts activityList